# RxJS: Observable never completes when using mergeMap with concurrent

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I'm using RxJS to call an asynchronous function for each element of the array.
I want to call the asynchronous function only if the element satisfies certain conditions, and I also want to limit the number of concurrent executions.

So I used the `mergeMap` operator with the `concurrent` parameter, but I have experienced strange behavior.

The minimum reproducible example is:

```
import { from, timer, mergeMap, EMPTY } from "rxjs";

from(Array(1000).keys()).pipe(
  mergeMap(n => n < 100 ? timer(10) : EMPTY, 10)
).subscribe({ complete: () => console.log('Complete') });
```

Suppose that `Array(1000).keys()` is the array, `n < 100` is the condition, and `timer(10)` is the asynchronous function.

I expected the observable to complete, but it didn't.

Strangely, the observable completes if the `concurrent` parameter is not specified, or the asynchronous function is called for all of the elements without the conditions.

```
// without concurrent parameter
mergeMap(n => n < 100 ? timer(10) : EMPTY)
// or without condition
mergeMap(n => timer(10), 10)
// or
mergeMap(n => EMPTY, 10)
```

I also observed the `next` values by the following code. (Note that I used `timer(10).pipe(map(() => n))` to get the input values)

```
import { from, timer, mergeMap, EMPTY, map } from "rxjs";

from(Array(1000).keys()).pipe(
  mergeMap(n => n < 100 ? timer(10).pipe(map(() => n)) : EMPTY, 10),
).subscribe({ next: console.log, complete: () => console.log('Complete') });
```

The output values stopped at 90.

```
...
86
87
88
89
90
```

I want to know why this behavior occurs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### How `mergeMap` works when `concurrent` is not specified

*When not specified, the `concurrent`'s value is `Infinity`.*

When a new value is received by `mergeMap`, it will create a new Observable(a.k.a *inner* Observable) based on the *project function*(i.e. the function provided to `mergeMap`) and it will subscribe to it.

Since the `concurrent` option has the value of `Infinity`, there can be as many incoming values as possible, `mergeMap` will create an *inner* Observable for each of them without any issues.

### How `mergeMap` works when `concurrent` is specified

When this option is specified, `mergeMap` will employ a [`buffer`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/7.8.1/src/internal/operators/mergeInternals.ts#L32) which will hold the exceeding values:

```
const outerNext = (value: T) => (active < concurrent ? doInnerSub(value) : buffer.push(value));
```

In the [code above](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/7.8.1/src/internal/operators/mergeInternals.ts#L53), we see that the buffer is populated with new values whenever the **number of active** inner Observables **exceeds** the number of **concurrent allowed**. The `outerNext` function is called when `mergeMap` receives values, such as [0, 999] from `Array(1000)`.

### Why the Observable does not complete

This code

```
import { from, timer, mergeMap, EMPTY } from "rxjs";

from(Array(1000).keys()).pipe(
  mergeMap(n => n < 100 ? timer(10) : EMPTY, 10)
).subscribe({ complete: () => console.log('Complete') });
```

will not complete due to an **implementation detail** that is used in the `doInnerSub()` function(the function called from `outerNext()`).

The gist is that it is a **recursive function**. This is a pseudo-code implementation of what it does(you can find the real implementation [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/7.8.1/src/internal/operators/mergeInternals.ts#L55-L133)):

```
const doInnerSub = value => {
  // Increase number of active connections.
  active++;

  // Creating from the projection function provided to `mergeMap`.
  createInnerObservable({
    // During the teardown phase(also when `finalize` is called).
    afterComplete: () => {
      if (hasInnerObservableCompleted) {
        // Making space for a new connection.
        active--;

        while (buffer.length && active < concurrent) {
          bufferedValue = buffer.shift()!;
          doInnerSub(bufferedValue);
        }
      }
    }
  });
}
```

After all the Observables created with `timer(10)` complete, only `EMPTY` Observables will be created. Such Observables **completed immediately as they're subscribed**. In other words, they complete synchronously. The result of this is that, after the 90th `timer(10)` Observable(90 = 100 - 10), these lines:

```
while (buffer.length && active < concurrent) {
  bufferedValue = buffer.shift()!;
  doInnerSub(bufferedValue);
}
```

will cause this error to be thrown:

[image]

Here's also a screenshot with the callstack that seems to prove that `doInnerSub()` is being called synchronously(and recursively) too many times.

[image]

### Why the Observable completes when `concurrent` is omitted

The answer is because `doInnerSub()` does not have to call itself anymore(because the buffer is no longer used). Basically, there will be 1000 inner Observables created.

### Why the Observable completes when no condition is used

For this case:

```
mergeMap(n => timer(10), 10)
```

the callstack will not keep on increasing because `timer(10)` involves an **asynchronous action**(i.e. `setInterval()`).

For this case:

```
mergeMap(n => EMPTY, 10)
```

Since `EMPTY` completes immediately as it is being subscribed, the **buffer won't be populated at all**. So, the *callstack exceeded* error can't occur.

[image]

In the above image, that breakpoint won't be hit at all.

### Why the values stop at 90

As to why it stops as 90, the reason is because `concurrent = 10`, so after the {100(from mergeMap condition) - concurrentValue(10)} `timer(10)` Observable, the callstack will keep on increasing because the first `EMPTY` Observable is taken from the buffer then from there the infinite recursion starts.

If you were to use, for instance, 11, the last value printed would be 89:

```
mergeMap((n) => (n < 100 ? timer(10) : EMPTY), 11),
```

[image]